# Why i can't calculate big numbers in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

[image: error on calculating big numbers]

[image: calculates small numbers]

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Button from './components/Button';
import { Input } from './components/input';
import * as math from 'mathjs';
import Header from '../src/components/Header';

const App=()=> {
  const buttons= [
 {id:7,symbol:"7"},{id:8,symbol:"8"},{id:9,symbol:"9"}]

  const buttons2=[{id:4,symbol:"4"},{id:5,symbol:"5"},{id:6,symbol:"6"},{id:'+',symbol:"+"}]
  
  const buttons3=[{id:1,symbol:"1"},{id:2,symbol:"2"},{id:3,symbol:"3"},{id:'-',symbol:"-"}]

  const buttons4=[{id:'.',symbol:"."},{id:0,symbol:"0"},{id:'/',symbol:"/"},{id:'*',symbol:"x"}

]


  const[text,setText]=useState("");
  const[result,setResult]=useState("");

  const addToText=(val)=>{
    setText((text)=>[...text, val+" "]);
  }

  const resetInput=()=>{
    setText("");
    setResult("");
  }   

 

  const calculateResult=()=>{
    try{
  const input=text.join("");
  setResult(math.evaluate(input));

  
}catch(err){
setResult("Error")
}
  }
```

I have tried differents method to solve the problem, but still have no idea why it doesn't work. Plaese Help. Project from frontend mentor. If you need more code let me know. Thankss you

Answer (score 0):

use `evaluate` function from `mathjs` library

```
import {evaluate} from 'mathjs';
```

then try some static strings. for example:

```
evaluate('sin(45 deg) ^ 2')    // 0.5
evaluate('9 / 3 + 2i')         // 3 + 2i
```

If the examples above work correctly and produce the expected results, then the issue may lie with the text string you are passing to the evaluate function. However, if the examples do not work as expected, it's possible that there's a problem with your import statement or the mathjs module itself. Double-check your import statement and ensure that you have correctly installed the mathjs package.

Answer (score 0):

```
const addToText = (val) => {
    setText((text) => [...text, val + " "]);
}
```

The mistake was in this code. I wrote `val + " "` instead of `val + ""`.
Therefore it didn't calculate big numbers. (For example: `55+58`)